# Create a parameter that all reports can use (SSRS and VS2008)

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

We use SSRS andour reports are in MS Visual Studio 2008.

I'm thinking there must be a special way of doing this, rather than building the same parameter in 200 reports.

Essentially, we maintain tables in SQL server that list a users information (name, region, windows nt identity, etc).  We have always had reports that just let users see all information (i.e. a user in Latin America could see data for Europe).  New requirements have made it so our reports can't do that any more.

In the past I've built reports where I set a parameter within reports called something like "myuser" and set it equal to the value [&UserID] and that gives me the users Windows login, which I then could join to the login in my SQL server tables, and run via queries/stored procdures to get my results.

This is all easy enough, except right now I'm looking at putting this parameter into about 200 existing reports, each time with the same information.  there has to be a way to make something like a "global" parameter that can be used by all reports in a given VS2008 solution, right?

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure there's no way to do what you're describing.  You might be able to do some creative xcopy/replace on your .rdlc files to add the parameter to all 200 reports.  That's about the best idea I've got right now.

Comment: I think you need an extra pair of hands more than anything else to get this done. Dont know of any way to deploy a variable to all the reports and make it work without tweaking the report definition itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Windows Integrarted authentication, then instead of maintaining a new parameter in your reports, you can use the `SYSTEM_USER` function in your SQL stored procedure, like this:

```
DECLARE @userName Nvarchar(200)
SELECT @userName = SYSTEM_USER
PRINT @userName
```

Hope it helps.